# How would someone make their own programming language

Tags: syntax

So i'm trying to make my own Programming Language but don't really know how. I have looked it up but people say try using Python to make it, well i mean how do you make your own language like to use python you would have to Install it, Well to use my language you would have to install it aswell. How would someone make it also add Syntax Highlighting. I have tried making it in Lua and i'm not to Successful

I'm not able to make everything like that, and i also wanna have my own custom Syntax Highlighting but choose the colors like this

```rb
Syntax = {
log/Log/LOG = Blue; -- Print Function

bringback = Red; -- return function
}


function ByteText(...)
 string.Byte(...) 
end
function CustomFunctionsName(data)
Do(Data)
end
```

So i'm kinda successfull in this but i don't want it running of Lua i don't mind using a Lua api or c# or python api but i just want to learn how to make it customly like how did python and LOLCODE make their own languages? I wan't to make it like that LOLCODE's functions are so random and i wanna make it Customly and my own way just like them, If someone can Explain that would be amazing <3

Answer (score 0):

You don't say why you'd *want* to write your own language when there are plenty available, but to answer your question....

Start by searching "language parsers" in your favorite search engine.
Learn about language parsing itself.  If you're still interested after that (and it isn't an easy topic if you intend to write something from scratch) you should be able to figure out where to go next.

---

P.S.
Your first worry is only about what your language will accomplish and what grammar it will support.  Stuff like syntax highlighting isn't something to worry about until after your language is written and can compile itself.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen "Language Parsing" allot when i search on this topic. +1

Comment: Without knowing your background, I don't know that this is a good place to start... but try https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-csharp/  (I haven't used it, but at least it seem thorough and it is free).